# Convert a .NET 4.5 portable class library to a Windows Store Class Library

Tags: windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

I've developed a library as a Portable Class Library, and now I'm finding that I need to make it Windows 8 Store App specific to make use of the Windows.Network namespace. Is there any way to automatically convert the project without completely hacking the .csproj file ?

Comment: Don't think the PCL project itself can be easily converted. Would it be an alternative to create a new *Windows 8* project in your solution and just drag-and-drop all files from the PCL project into the *Windows 8* project? Alternatively, create a new *Windows 8* project that consumes the PCL project?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in VS 2013 Update 2.  If you are OK with targeting Windows 8.1 in your library, just deselect all the other platforms in the targeting dialog.  If you need to target Windows 8, there isn't a way to do this directly, but retargeting to Windows 8.1 and then changing the version property in the .csproj file to 8.0 (I think it's TargetPlatformVersion in this case) should probably work.

Comment: Daniel: under which conditions can a PCL be re-targeted to a single target (in VS2013.2)? Is there any documentation on this somewhere?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson It can be retargeted to a single target if the single target is "Windows 8.1" or "Windows Phone 8.1".  Also, you can retarget libraries targeting a single one of those platforms to add additional platforms.  This is briefly mentioned here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx  It's also covered in these blog posts: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/03/the-next-generation-of-net.aspx http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/21/sharing-code-across-platforms.aspx